# Are there any abstract rings like there are groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

For example, in groups we have things like isometries, permutations, etc, but I haven't seen these more abstract objects in ring theory. All I see in ring theory are rings like the integers and reals etc.

Comment: I don't really agree that permutations aren't a concrete object. But yes, sure we do. A ring is anything satisfying the given axioms, and you can come up with such things that are as exotic as you'd like.

Comment: Similar to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6507/are-there-broad-or-powerful-theorems-of-rings-that-do-not-involve-the-familiar-n

Comment: any abelian group with multiplication described trivially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the endomorphism ring of an abelian group, with composition as multiplication?

Comment: And this is Cayley's theorem for rings.